# How do I extend Java classes by Reflection?

Tags: java

I have two Strings:

```
String a="org.test.A";
String b="org.test.B";
```

I get a class by Reflection

```
Class aClass = Class.forName(a);
```

I want aClass extends b, like:

```
Class okClass=aClass.extends(b);//how to implement this?
```

how to implement this?

how to get okClass?

thanks!

Comment: Are classes A and B already defined elsewhere? What properties exactly do you expect okClass to have?? The question makes no sense as it is.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Apart from using a [JDK dynamic proxy](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/reflection/proxy.html), which works only by interface, you can use [CGLIB](http://cglib.sourceforge.net/) or javassist for extending classes at runtime.

Answer (score 4):

Generally speaking you want to be able to create new classes (not objects) at runtime. You can use [bytecode engineering](http://java-sources.org/open-source/bytecode-libraries) or [java compiler api](http://www.j2ee.me/javase/6/docs/api/javax/tools/JavaCompiler.html) for that.

Comment: These links are dead, can you update them?

Answer (score 3):

You could start by reading up on [dynamic proxies](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html). Proxies do not extend classes, but they do implement interfaces which you can map on your class implementation through the invocation handler.

Answer (score 0):

As said before I'd recommend to look at CGLIB but there is also [javassist](http://www.csg.is.titech.ac.jp/~chiba/javassist/) which is a class library for editing bytecodes...