# In Android (or Java itself), is it possible to a class to inherit from a class referenced by name?

Tags: java, android

Times ago, I was looking for a way to start ServiceMode programmatically. The great obstacle was how to understand the parameters that the class must receive (in its case, it is the SECRET CODES). And off course, the device **must be rooted**.

It had demanded plenty of research but I finally figured out how to start a system activity through command line. Now I want to create a class that extends from it. However, I don't have its API reference because it is hidded in Android internals and only accessible through things like reflection. I have only its name:  **com.sec.android.app.servicemodeapp.ServiceModeApp**.

So, I'm wondering if Android/Java API let me create a class declaration in the form of:

```
public class MyCustomSystemActivity extends Class.forName("com.sec.android.app.servicemodeapp.ServiceModeApp") { ... }
```

Of course, this sentence is not allowed.

Can someone give me a hint if it is possible in other ways? And if yes, how can I declare such thing?

Comment: What makes you think that `com.sec.android.app.servicemodeapp.ServiceModeApp` exists in your process in the first place?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I extend Java classes by Reflection?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1886785/how-do-i-extend-java-classes-by-reflection)

Comment: CommonsWare, I'm sure of it because I can invoke it by using "adb shell am start -n the.package.name/the.class.name". Also, I can look at its tag in LogCat.

Comment: You have indicated that this is an activity exists in an app that you did not write. You are writing a different app. What makes you think that this class will exist in *your app* and your process's Dalvik virtual machine? You cannot inherit from a class that is not in your virtual machine. So, where do you think you are getting this class from?

Comment: Well... that is the point where I'm looking for an answer. I don't have its definition within my app. But I'm wondering if I can get a reference of it from Android's /system/app directory, in some way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is not possible.  In a compiled language such as Java, the compiler needs to know what members are inherited and what methods are overridden, and it can't do this if it doesn't know what class is being extended.

Comment: I'll consider your answer ajb. It is very convincing the assertion that I can't get any reference from an already compiled app.