# Choose which subclass to extend from at runtime in java

Tags: java, android, oop, design-patterns, subclass

I have two classes (say B & C) that both derive from a class (say A). Now I need to write a class (say D) that should dynamically derive either from B or C at runtime.

B, C & A are classes provided to me through libraries and the only class in my control is D class. How do I write D with respect to constraints mentioned above. Obviously B and C have come from different vendors and hence would need different methods to be overridden in D depending on which is its parent class.

I cannot write different versions of D that would subclass from B & C since the override methods would have same code under different method names.

Comment: I'm not sure that's possible in Java, unless you use reflection. Can you not define an *interface* instead, which acts as a proxy for class `D`?

Comment: have you seen this link? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1886785/how-do-i-extend-java-classes-by-reflection

Answer (score 4):

You should define an interface `I`, then define concrete implementations that correspond to `B` and `C`. At runtime you can determine which implementation of `I` is necessary, perhaps using a factory method. Then your code need only call methods of `I` instead of methods of `B` or `C`.

**EDIT**

There seems to be some confusion about how this works. What you want is for your business logic to operate on a consistent, stable API that belongs to you. For this you create an interface which we'll call `I`. Now you need implementation classes for the different external classes you need to adapt to (`A`, `B`, and `C`). It might look something like this:

```
public interface I {
    void doSomething();
}

public class IA implements I {
    private A a;

    public IA(A a) {
        this.a = a;
    }

    public void doSomething() {
        // specific to A
        a.doSomethingUnique();
    }
}

// similar implementation classes for B and C
```

Now you need to obtain an instance of `I` at runtime specific to your current situation. Whatever informs you about which specific class is in use at runtime can be used for this purpose. At worst, you can do this:

```
// in some util class
public static I getI(Object obj) {
    if (obj instanceof A) {
        return new IA((A) obj);
    } else if (obj instanceof B) {
        return new IB((B) obj);
    } else if (obj instanceof C) {
        return new IC((C) obj);
    }
    // maybe throw an exception? or return a mock I implementation?
}
```

Now all your business logic refers only to instances of `I` and calls methods defined in your interface, abstracting away the different concrete classes you have no control over.

Comment: Bingo. In other words, put both `B` and `C` in (their own) wrapper objects, whose classes both implementing `I`, then use the wrapper classes instead of directly accessing `B` and `C`.

Comment: I clearly wrote that A, B & C are not under my control at all. My class currently derives from A. Now I have to selectively enable derive from B or C and do the same code in different callbacks.

Comment: There is nothing about this solution that requires A, B, or C to be under your control at all. This pattern is widely used to adapt the interface of an existing class (or classes) to another without modifying their source. It's called the Adapter Pattern, read about it here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern

Comment: The problem is none of classes A,B & C is an interface.

Comment: A, B, & C do not have to be interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with private inheritance.

If you have :

```
class A
{
  public void methodA() {...}
}
class B extends A
{
  public void methodB() {...}
}
class C extends A
{
  public void methodC() {...}
}
```

D would be implemented as :

```
class D
{
  private B b;
  private C c;
  private D() {}
  public static D instantiateAsB()
  {
    D res = new D();
    res.b = new B();
  }
  public static D instantiateAsC()
  {
    D res = new D();
    res.c = new C();
  }
  public void methodA()
  {
    if ( b!=null )
      b.methodA();
    else
      c.methodA();
  }
  public foid methodB() 
  {
    if ( b==null )
      throw new MethodNotImplementedException();
    else
      b.methodB();
  }
  public foid methodC()
  {
    if ( c==null )
      throw new MethodNotImplementedException();
    else
      c.methodC();
  }
}
```

Private inheritance has some drawbacks. One is that D would not be an A. So you can't pass a D object as a parameter to a method which requires an A. This code would not compile :

```
void method( A a ) {...}

D d = D.instantiateAsB();
method( d );
```

You can work around that using cast methods in D's definition :

```
// inside D class :
public A castAsA()
{
  if ( b!=null )
    return (A)b;
  else
    return (A)c;
}

public B castAsB()
{
  if ( b==null )
    throw new ClassCastException();
  else
    return b;
}

public C castAsC()
{
  if ( c==null )
    throw new ClassCastException();
  else
    return c;
}
```

And the previous non compiling code would be rewritten as :

```
D d = D.instantiateAsB()
method( d.castAsA() );
```